# unfocus selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

after page load, the first selectbox will be auto-focus.  how to use jquery to unfocus the selectbox after page finished loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) ? E.g.

```
$(function() {
    $('select:eq(0)').blur();
});
```